# Is $|\langle Ax, y\rangle|^4 \leq \langle |A|^{2}x, x\rangle\langle |A^*|^{2}y, y\rangle$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$.

> Why
>   \begin{equation}
> |\langle Ax, y\rangle|^4 \leq \langle |A|^{2}x, x\rangle\langle |A^*|^{2}y, y\rangle,
> \end{equation}
>   for every $x,y\in H$. Note that $|X|=(X^*X)^{1/2}$ is the absolute value of an operator $X$.

I think that the above inequality is used in the following proof

[image]

Comment: There is nothing even remotely resembling that inequality in this proof. Why do you think it was used?

Comment: But what the  authors of the  paper  used? Thanks

Comment: It's called the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. It says so right there. That and the defintion of the norm $\|\phantom x\|$, and of the adjoint $T^*$.

Comment: But by the Cauchy-Schwarz we have only $$|\langle Tx, x\rangle|^2 \leq \langle |T|^{2}x, x\rangle\langle x,x\rangle$$

Comment: Let's see. I mentioned three things they used. You've figured out how they used one of them (note the bit about $x$ being a unit vector). Now figure out where the other two came in.

Comment: I don't understand how the factor $1/2$ will appear

Comment: Those are exponents, not factors. they appear by taking the square root of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality result you've quoted.

Comment: Since $\|x\|=1$, then 
$$|\langle Tx, x \rangle|^2 \leq \langle |T|^{2}x, x\rangle^{1/2}\langle |T|^{2}x, x\rangle^{1/2},
$$
But
$$\langle |T|^{2}x, x\rangle^{1/2}=\|Tx\|$$
and
$$\langle |T^*|^{2}x, x\rangle^{1/2}=\|T^*x\|.$$
I know that $\|Tx\|=\|T^*x\|$ when $T$ is normal.

Comment: The definition of the adjoint is $\langle T^*x, y\rangle = \langle x, Ty\rangle$ for all $x,y$. And they are not turning $\langle |T^2|x,y\rangle^{1/2}$ into $\|Tx\|$. The definition of the norm was used earlier, in the equality portion. However, they are using that $|\langle x,y\rangle| = |\langle y,x \rangle|$.

Comment: I'm sorry because I don't understand your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}|\langle Tx,x\rangle|^2 + \|Tx\|^4 &= |\langle Tx,x\rangle|^2 + \left(\sqrt{\langle Tx, Tx \rangle}\right)^4\\&=|\langle Tx,x\rangle|^2 +|\langle Tx, Tx \rangle|^2\\&=|\langle Tx,x\rangle|^2 + |\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle|^2\end{align}$$

is the first line of the calculation. Though not directly mentioned, they continue it as:
$$\begin{align}|\langle Tx,x\rangle|^2 + |\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle|^2 &= |\langle Tx,x\rangle|\,|\langle Tx,x\rangle| + |\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle|\,|\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle|\\
&=|\langle Tx,x\rangle|\,|\langle x,Tx\rangle| + |\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle|\,|\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle|\\
&=|\langle Tx,x\rangle|\,|\langle T^*x,x\rangle| + |\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle|\,|\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle|\end{align}$$
where the fact that $|\langle u,v\rangle| = |\langle v,u\rangle|$ was used in the 2nd line, and the definition of the adjoint was used in the third.

Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz (with square roots) to each of the 4 expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much Professor for your great help. I think my claim holds only if $x=y$. Do you agree with me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: For any $x, y_0 \ne 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that it holds for all $y = ay_0$ with $0 \le a \le \delta$. This is because the LH side varies with $a^4$ while the RH side varies with $a^2$. (FYI - I may be old and creeky, but I've never been a professor.)